# Python Paho client how to consume from RabbitMQ existing queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, mqtt, paho

I have a RabittMQ queue '**test**' and I have to write a python consumer using Paho client to consume message from this ('**test**') queue only.

below is my consumer code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

server = "<machine_ip>"
port = 1883
username = "test"
password = "test"
#########################
client_id = "test_consumer"
topic = "test"

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic)

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
 data = str(msg.payload.decode());
 print(data)

client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set(username,password)
client.connect(server, port, 60, bind_address="")
client.loop_forever()
```

but when I am starting consumer it is creating a new queue as in attached screenshot, which I don't want. any solution for this ?

[image]

Comment: Does it create a new queue whenever you execute client?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why rabbitmq creates a queue for each client (publisher or subscriber/consumer), but if you use parameters bellow, all clients will use same queue:

1. First of all, you need to connect and subscribe the consumer with:
    clean_session=False, 
   And subscribe a topic ('text' for example) with qos=1
2. You can disconnect consumer (if you want, for simulate a network disconnection)
3. Next, connect your publisher with:
   clean_session=False
   And publish with to the same topic ('test') with qos=1, retain=False

Answer (score 0):

1. Create virtual host '**benz**'
2. Create queue '**test**' with routing key '**eff41a11134d4fb9bd0325866b8a983d**'
3. Create new user

**Note** - You have to create a new user for this, RabittMQ will not work with the default username/password for below producer and consumer.

producer.py -

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1883
vhost = "benz"
routing_key= "eff41a11134d4fb9bd0325866b8a983d"
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

client = mqtt.Client()
client.username_pw_set(vhost + ':' + username, password)
client.connect(ip, port, 60)

while True:
    console_input = str(input())
    print (console_input)
    client.publish(routing_key, payload=console_input, qos=0)
```

consumer.py

```
import pika

from demjson import decode

## RabittMQ configuration properties ##
ip = '127.0.0.1'
vhost = 'benz'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
queue_name = 'test'

url = 'amqp://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + ip + ':5672/' + vhost
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    data = str(body.decode());
    print(data)

channel.basic_consume(queue_name, callback, auto_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
connection.close()
```